# The right method for animation once the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, load, opacity

I would like to set up animations of appearance once the page loaded. The **problem is** that before the CSS is loaded the elements arrive suddenly, and finally, once I have all that is loaded I have my animation that starts. It's not very cool visually.

The solution that I came up with defaults opacity on the container! Not sure, The problem is that if the browser does not support animations, the user will see the site with an opacity of `0`. In other words, he will not see anything.

So are there ways to do it?

PS: **I tried** a lot of searches on Google without ever finding the answer to my question, maybe I have not used the right terms.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping browser compatibility in mind is very important. However, your desired result can be achieved with CSS Animations and little stress: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation.

If you provide some HTML and CSS a more specific answer could be provided. But, I would recommend defining keyframes for each element you want to animate (several could use the same one if desired) and use this for a one time animation at site load. No JS necessary.